# Handling Stripe errors with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, stripe-payments

I am attempting to charge a user when they create an account. Everything is set up and working perfect with the code before. When a user sign's up for a "premium" section of the website they have an account created and are charged with the code below.

The problem: If a user's credit card ends up getting declined for various reasons... their user account is STILL created. How would I change my code below to not reach that part of the code if the credit card fails?

Note: this DOES work for when the user trys to create an account with a username that is taken. The web app redirects them to /buy to select a new username. However it does not work to handle the credit card errors because the user is created first.

Thank you for the help!

```
 user.save(function(err) {
            console.log('this is the problem' + ' ' + err)
            if(err){
            return res.redirect('/buy')
            }
            var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
            var charge = stripe.charges.create({
            amount: 749,
            currency: "usd",
            description: "Website.com Premium - One time Payment",
            source: token,

            }, function(err, charge) {
                if(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  return res.redirect('/buy')
                }
                console.log('charged')
                req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                  if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                  }
                  console.log('all looks good')
                  res.redirect('/results');
                });
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: What about removing the user upon charge failure? You could swap the order, charge -> user (sort just pushing the problem boundary around though).  It's not a bad idea to perform some kind of failure clean up though. The bigger issue here is partial request success / failure across multiple services which has many challenges. I would suggest thinking about "cleaning up" upon certain errors via (usr.remove) upon charge fail.

Comment: Hmm. How do you "user.remove" with passport?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PassportJS and Stripe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788021/passportjs-and-stripe)

Comment: Does this even work? According to the docs: "Charging cards with Stripe is a synchronous process. Your code will immediately receive the result of the request: either a Charge object upon success or an exception upon failure. No asynchronous webhook or IPN script is required."